# Populate int array with a char array full of numbers in C (char array to int array)

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

My Char array allows for a user to input a purely numeric string, thus storing each digit in its own array space. I need to assign each element of the char array to the corresponding location in the int array. How do i store the actual numeral rather than the the ASCII equivalent

ex. if I enter 9 as the string, i don't want  57 (the ASCII value) but the numeral 9.

```
int main()   
{

    int x[256] = {0};
    int y[256] = {0};

    char temp1[256] = {0};
    char temp2[256] = {0};

    char sum[256] = {0};
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%s", &temp1); 

    printf("Please enter second number: ");
    scanf("%s", &temp2);

    for(i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        x[i] = ((int)temp1[i]);
        y[i] = ((int)temp2[i]);         
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
    x[i] = ((int)temp1[i]);
    y[i] = ((int)temp2[i]);
```

to:

```
    x[i] = temp1[i] - '0';
    y[i] = temp2[i] - '0';
```

Note that you also need to fix your `scanf` calls - change:

```
printf("Please enter a number: ");
scanf("%s", &temp1); 

printf("Please enter second number: ");
scanf("%s", &temp2);
```

to:

```
printf("Please enter a number: ");
scanf("%s", temp1); 

printf("Please enter second number: ");
scanf("%s", temp2);
```

Comment: Thats brilliant, why though do we need to subtract the '0' from the char?  btw, that fixed it, thanks

Comment: Oh I figured out the why.  When we store the char 9 to the string, it stores it as the ASCII 57, subtracting the char 0 (ASCII 48) will result in '9' and that value is then stored in the integer. awesome thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void) {
int x = 0;
int y = 0 
char input[12] = {0}; --->initialize var input 


scanf("%s", &input[0]);
int ch_len = strlen(input)/sizeof(char); --create length of input[] array
int digit[ch_len];    --->initialize digit which size is how many character in input[] array
fflush(stdin);

while (input[y] != '\0') {
if (isdigit(input[y])) {
    digit[x++] = input[y++]-'0';
    count++;
}
else y++;
}
}
```